# Displaying a custom post types custom taxonomy value?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, theme-development, terms

I've got a custom post type with multiple custom taxonomies + metaboxes. I've used multiple approaches from the codex and other on line resources but none seem to work. I basically want to display the current posts taxonomy values below the title on each custom post's page. This is what I have so far...

**In functions.php:**

```
function discography_album_label() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Labels', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Label', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Labels' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Labels' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Label' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Label:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Label' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Label' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Label' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Label' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Labels' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'label' ),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'discography_album_label', 'discography', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'discography_album_label', 0 );
```

**In single-discography.php**

```
$genreTax = get_taxonomies( '', 'names' );
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $genreTax,  array("fields" => "names", "orderby" => "type"));

<p><?php print_r($terms);?></p>
```

However all this is outputting is:

```
Array ( [0] => Ska [1] => Reggae [2] => Record Label )
```

...which doesn't really help as it's the values for the "Labels" **and** and the "Genres" taxonomies (with no way of differentiating which is from which). How can I get just the value for one of these taxonomies?

Comment: try `get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'discography_album_label' )`

Comment: After trying:

`$albumGenres = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'discography_album_label' );`
`<?php print_r($albumGenres);?>`

I see:
`Array ( [17] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 17 [name] => Record Label [slug] => record-label [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 17 [taxonomy] => discography_album_label [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [object_id] => 43 [filter] => raw ) )`

How can I **just** get the `name` value? I tried `<?php print_r($albumGenres->name);?>` but nothing

Comment: you need to loop through the array of objects returned by `get_the_terms()` and then grab the `name` property. `foreach ( $albumGenres as $albumGenre ) { echo $albunGenre->name; }`

Comment: Ahh ofcourse... thanks, post this as the answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$albumGenres = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'discography_album_label' );
foreach ( $albumGenres as $albumGenre ) {
  echo $albumGenre->name; // or whatever value
}
```